# Can you still earn the question view badges for a question with bounty?

Tags: support, badges, bounties

If I ask a question and then add a bounty to it (after the 48 hour waiting period), and it amasses 1k, 2.5k, or 10k views, will I still earn the 'Popular Question,' 'Notable Question,' or 'Famous Question' badges, respectfully? Or does adding a bounty disqualify you for those badges on that given question, due to you "buying" your question views?

Comment: umm.... why not??? (and the trivial answer here is: yes)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I feel like the point of those badges is to reward the user for coming up with a good question, but by using a bounty, you are attracting attention to a question that might not necessarily have been good to begin with

Comment: You are overthinking it way too much. Those badges are simple: when a question reach X amount of views, the user who posted the question gets a badge. No complications. This is all explained in the faq, if there are complications, they are mentioned in there. In case of the badges you mention here, no complications like I said. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I understand that you might feel this is trivial, but as someone who is not as experienced with the SE network, it was not obvious to me

Comment: You might be right. Still, I don't think answer like "Yes, you can still earn" is valid here, better be closed as duplicate of the faq explaining about all of the badges.

Comment: @Harshal not enough detail? What details you want? The answer is simply "no", nothing to add to that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bounties, downvotes, closure then re-opening, earthquakes or volcanoes will not disqualify you from earning the popular question badge, or the other similar badges.